# Text and other things inside not change to card color...I am new to designing help would be appreciated

Tags: html, css, jsp, bootstrapper

image is attached Why card background not applied to texts. Text and other things inside not change to card color...I am new to designing help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

 <form action="/login" method="post">  
    <div class="container">   
    <div class="card" style="overflow: auto; background: white; width: 400px;margin: auto; margin- 
  top: 100px;">
    <div class="card-body" style="overflow: auto; background: white">
    
 
   
    <h1>Login</h1>
        <p>Please Enter Email and Password to Login.</p>
        
    
    
       <b>Username :</b> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>  
        
        <label><b>Password </b>: </label>   
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" style="margin-left: 5px;" name="password" 
required> 
       
        <button type="submit" class="register" style="margin-left: 85px;">Login</button>   
        <button class="register" style="margin-left: 15px;" type="button">Home</button>
       
       
        
   


       
           </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>   
</form>   
 </body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdxp7.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap? Your card background colour given as white. Would be appreciate if you give more details what do you want to achieve. if you want to change your card text colours to same as body then you can add style to header or online

```
<style type="text/css">
.card {
   color: red; /* replace with your actual colour #1680cc */
}
</style>
```

Comment: after apply this i am getting this

https://imgur.com/a/LWvNnTB.

Comment: Without seeing your full CSS/HTML for this page it is difficult answer. Could you please update source code for this page.

Comment: Solved my problem but I had to add background white inside card body...like for text paragraph etc i had to add background:white else it was showing purple background as you can see in image.